# Problem using RefreshIndicator widget with bloc pattern

Tags: dart, flutter, pull-to-refresh, bloc

I have a class called A which is a `Stateless` class and I have a class called B which is a `Stateful` class

The build method of A class is as follows

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      bloc: DashboardListBloc(),
      child: Scaffold(
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SafeArea(child: _dashboardAppBar(context)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            B() // this is class B
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
```

I have declared my bloc object in B class
Suppose in body of class A, i wrap `SingleChildScrollView` with `RefreshIndicator`, so how in its refresh property
i am supposed to call the methods of Bloc class whose reference are defined in class B.

I thought of moving everything to class B and removing class A but 
that causes another problem as i have to initialise `Bloc` in init method and as init is called before build,
bloc will always result in null as i will be using `BlocProvider` `InheritedWidget` in build method of class B

Answer (score 0):

You should create one single bloc instance and provide it to both classes.
In other words your bloc should not be created in class B but instead you can create your bloc by wrapping any common parent of A and B (such as your App widget) with a  `BlocProvider` and using the `create` method. Then in any child widget you can do `BlocProvider.of<MyBloc>()` or `context.read<MyBloc>()` and this way both classes A and B will share the same Bloc instance.